# How do I merge two arrays of hashes by one of the hash keys value?

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays of hashes:

```
[{:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a"},
{:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a"},
{:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a"}]

[{:status=>"success", :sender=>"ayfw-a"},
{:status=>"success", :sender=>"vpfw-a"}]
```

The keys I can use to merge are `:node` and `:sender`.
I need to add the `:status` parameter from the second array to the first array as `:another_status`, putting "skipped" where there's no corresponding `:sender` in the second array, like this:

```
[{:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a", :another_status=>"skipped"},
{:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a", :another_status=>"success"},
{:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a", :another_status=>"success"}]
```

I can't come up with a solution to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
a1 = [
  {:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a"},
  {:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a"},
  {:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a"},
]

a2 = [
  {:status=>"success", :sender=>"ayfw-a"},
  {:status=>"success", :sender=>"vpfw-a"},
]

sender_status = Hash[ a2.map { |item| [ item[:sender], item[:status] ] } ]

a1.each do |item|
  item[:another_status] = sender_status[item[:node]] || 'skipped'
end

a1.each { |item| p item }
```

**output**

```
{:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a", :another_status=>"skipped"}
{:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a", :another_status=>"success"}
{:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a", :another_status=>"success"}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a1 = [{:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a"},
{:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a"},
{:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a"}]

a2 = [{:status=>"success", :sender=>"ayfw-a"},
{:status=>"success", :sender=>"vpfw-a"}]

a1.map do |h1| h1.merge(another_status:
  a2.find{|h2| h2[:sender] == h1[:node]}.to_h[:status] || "skipped"
) end
```

output

```
[
  {
    :status         => "failed",
    :tag            => "tag156",
    :node           => "isfw-a",
    :another_status => "skipped"
  },
  {
    :status         => "unchanged",
    :tag            => "tag156",
    :node           => "ayfw-a",
    :another_status => "success"
  },
  {
    :status         => "changed",
    :tag            => "tag156",
    :node           => "vpfw-a",
    :another_status => "success"
  }
]
```

Comment: It's always good to show the results of your code, hint, hint.

Answer (score -1):

```
ar1 = [ {:status=>"failed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"isfw-a"},
        {:status=>"unchanged", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"ayfw-a"},
        {:status=>"changed", :tag=>"tag156", :node=>"vpfw-a"}]

ar2 = [{:status=>"success", :sender=>"ayfw-a"},
       {:status=>"success", :sender=>"vpfw-a"}]

new_hsh = ar1.map do |a1| 
  bol = ar2.select{|a2| a2[:sender] == a1[:node] }
  bol ? a1[:another_status]=bol[:status] : a1[:another_status]= 'skipped'
  a1
end

new_ary
# => [{:status=>"failed",
#      :tag=>"tag156",
#      :node=>"isfw-a",
#      :another_status=>"skipped"},
#     {:status=>"unchanged",
#      :tag=>"tag156",
#      :node=>"ayfw-a",
#      :another_status=>"success"},
#     {:status=>"changed",
#      :tag=>"tag156",
#      :node=>"vpfw-a",
#      :another_status=>"success"}]
```

Comment: The requirement is to populate the `:another_status` value in the `ar1` hashes from the `:status` value from the corresponding `ar2` hash. Instead it is just setting it to literal `'success'`.